# How do I get the values from Npgsql if I use Select with multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

If for example I have this query:

```
SELECT (column1, column2, column3) FROM table
```

And I ran ExecuteReader().
If column1 and column3 are strings and column 2 is an Id which are integers.
How do I get the values from each column? I tried it with the normal Get functions from the Reader, I would always get a Cast Exception Error can't cast database type to string/int

/ Edit
This is my test code:

```
            conn1.Open();
            string sql_reader = "SELECT (id, employee_number, first_name, last_name) FROM employee";
            using var cmd_reader = new NpgsqlCommand(sql_reader, conn1);

            var reader = cmd_reader.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(reader.GetFieldValue<int>(0));
            }
            conn1.Close();
```

I would get a "System.InvalidCastException" if I ran this code.
And if I would change `reader.GetFieldValue<int>(0)` to `reader.GetFieldValue<string>(1)` I would get an out of range error "column must be between 0 and 0".

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, in your case, each line will consist of an array of objects with a length equal to 4.

```
conn1.Open();
string sql_reader = "SELECT (id, employee_number, first_name, last_name) FROM employee";
using var cmd_reader = new NpgsqlCommand(sql_reader, conn1);

using var reader = cmd_reader.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var value = reader.GetFieldValue<object[]>(0);//value.Length is 4
    //I assumed that "id" and "employee_number" are int in your table.
    //value[0] is id
    //value[1] is employee_number
    //...
}
conn1.Close();
```

Starting with Npgsql 6.0:

```
conn1.Open();
string sql_reader = "SELECT (id, employee_number, first_name, last_name) FROM employee";
using var cmd_reader = new NpgsqlCommand(sql_reader, conn1);

using var reader = cmd_reader.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    using var internalReader = reader.GetData(0);//row reader
    while(internalReader.Read())
    {
        var id = internalReader.GetFieldValue<int>(0);
        var employee_number = internalReader.GetFieldValue<int>(1);
        var first_name = internalReader.GetFieldValue<string>(2);
        var last_name = internalReader.GetFieldValue<string>(3);
    }
}
conn1.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses.

In all other databases they are useless noise, but in Postgres the expression `(column1, column2, column3)` creates an anonymous record - so your result contains only a single column (which is that anonymous record that contains three fields).

e.g. this sample data:

```
create table t1 (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
insert into t1 values (1,2,3);
```

Then this query:

```
select (c1, c2, c3) as rec
from t1;
```

returns:

```
rec    
-------
(1,2,3)
```

But this

```
select c1, c2, c3
from t1;
```

returns the expected result

```
c1 | c2 | c3
---+----+---
 1 |  2 |  3
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=38120f5d69da844601b04872eb56072c)

Comment: How do I separate the values with NpgSql?

Comment: I don't know C#, but I would be very surprised if there isn't a method to get the value for each column separately from the result.

Comment: @LancePidor that depends on how you're interacting with PostgreSQL: raw ADO.NET, Dapper, or some ORM. If using Npgsql directly (raw ADO.NET), just call GetFieldValue on NpgsqlDataReader and pass the index of the column each time ([see the getting started docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#commands)).

Comment: @ShayRojansky Can you give an example? I tried the GetFieldValue and it didn't work. If I use GetFieldValue<string>(any number > 0) I would get an out of range error, if use 0 I would get a invalid cast error "Can't cast database type record to string/int".

Comment: @LancePidor there's an example in the link above. You have to make sure to read the correct type, so if you're reading integers from the database, you'd use reader.GetInt32().